# Graphite/Grafana query wildcard for unknown level

Tags: grafana, graphite

Is it possible to write a query to match all of these metrics:

```
foo.bar.something1.ending_word
foo.bar.something1.something2.ending_word
foo.bar.something1.something_else.ending_word
foo.bar.something1.something2.something3.something4.ending_word
foo.bar.ending_word
```

Something like this:

```
foo.bar[*].ending_word
```

?

I am trying to use this to query data in Grafana:
[image: grafana]

Comment: You referenced aliasByTag in your title, which controls naming.  It appears to me that you're actually trying to (a) access value, and (b) access that value by its name, not by tag.  Can you clarify what it is you're actually trying to do here?

Comment: @JefferMC I just realised how wrong was this question asked, thanks :) 
(Made some edits to make it clear)

Answer (score 0):

If your metrics are not tagged metrics, then you have to use the normal target expression syntax, in which case wildcards cannot cover indeterminite levels.  Reference [the graphite doc on this](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/render_api.html#paths-and-wildcards):

> All wildcards apply only within a single path element. In other words,
> they do not include or cross dots (.). Therefore, servers.* will not
> match servers.ix02ehssvc04v.cpu.total.user, while servers.*.*.*.*
> will.

If your metrics are tagged metrics, then you must use seriesByTag() and in this case the name may be treated as "just another" tag called "name" in the seriesByTag() function.  You may use regular expressions in seriesByTag() by using "name=~regEx", which means you can use .* to cover as many levels as you want. See the [graphite docs on querying by tags](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tags.html#querying) for additional information.

If you can't control the metric naming such that you can use tagging, I don't see a way to do what you want.  Be warned that switching a metric to being tagged means that you'll have to change all existing references to it (as well as migrate the data).

There may be some way to do this in Grafana, but I don't know Grafana.